# Automatic bibliographies by categories (\bibbycategory) not displayed if inside a refsection environment

Tags: biblatex

In the following MCE, bibliographies by categories are inserted:

1. manually, thanks to `\printbibliography[category=...]`,
2. automatically, thanks to `\bibbycategory`,

and are displayed as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
%
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
%
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{secondary}
%
\defbibheading{primary}{\subsection*{Primary Sources}}
\defbibheading{secondary}{\subsection*{Secondary Sources}}
% 
\addtocategory{primary}{aristotle:anima}
\addtocategory{secondary}{nussbaum}
%
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%
\begin{document}
% \begin{refsection}
  \autocite{aristotle:anima,nussbaum}
  %
  \section{Manual bibliographies by categories}
  \printbibliography[category=primary,title={Primary Sources}]
  \printbibliography[category=secondary,title={Secondary Sources}]
  %
  \section{Automatic bibliographies by categories}
  \printbibheading
  \bibbycategory
% \end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

But, if both are enclosed in a `refsection` environment, bibliographies by categories inserted:

1. manually, are displayed as expected,
2. automatically, are not displayed (and the LaTeX warning “Empty bibliography on input line ...” is issued).

Do you understand why and how to get around this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `\bibbycategory`: It forces refsection 0 and ignores the current refsection.

It should be fixed in https://github.com/plk/biblatex/commit/81a5e01777e0b3a79a4d12a3b790f233a9922c3d (https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1266), which will be part of the next `biblatex` release.

If you need a workaround in the meantime, you can go with

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{primary}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{secondary}

\defbibheading{primary}{\subsection*{Primary Sources}}
\defbibheading{secondary}{\subsection*{Secondary Sources}}

\addtocategory{primary}{aristotle:anima}
\addtocategory{secondary}{nussbaum}

\begin{document}
 \begin{refsection}
  \autocite{aristotle:anima,nussbaum}

  \section{Manual bibliographies by categories}
  \printbibliography[category=primary,title={Primary Sources}]
  \printbibliography[category=secondary,title={Secondary Sources}]

  \section{Automatic bibliographies by categories}
  \printbibheading
  \edef\therealrefsection{\therefsection}
  \bibbycategory[section=\therealrefsection]
 \end{refsection}
\end{document}
```

to explicitly force the current refsection.